# python while loop error

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

This is part of my python code. After I enter a different letter which is not c/l/d, it must ask "are there any animals." But it doesnt work. After I enter adifferent letter it asks "averege speed for a hour?" only one more time asks this, then asks me "are there any animal?"

I want to when I enter different letter code ask me "are there any animal?"

```
type=input("enter the type of animal(cheetah:c,lion:l,deer:d):") 
speed=float(input("average speed for a hour(km):")
while answer=="Y" or answer=="y":
      while type=="c" or type=="d" or type=="l":
            if type=="c":
               ceetah_count+=1
               total_c_speed+=speed
            elif type=="d":
                 deer_count+=1
                 total_d_speed+=speed
            else:
            lion_count+=1
            total_l_speed+=speed
            animal_count+=1
            total_speed+=speed
            type=input("enter the type of animal(cheetah:c,lion:l,deer:d):")
            speed=float(input("average speed for a hour(km):)
       answer=input("are there any animals?(yes:y/no:n):)`
```

Comment: **Unclear what you're asking**. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: please have a look at your code as the indentation is messed up

Comment: You need a colon after `while answer=="Y" or answer=="y"`: and `while type=="c" or type=="d" or type=="l"`:

Answer (score 0):

You have to reorder your `input`s:

```
while True:
    type=input("enter the type of animal(cheetah:c,lion:l,deer:d):") 
    if type in ('c', 'd', 'l'):
        speed=float(input("average speed for a hour(km):")
        if type=="c":
            ceetah_count+=1
            total_c_speed+=speed
        elif type=="d":
                deer_count+=1
                total_d_speed+=speed
        else:
            lion_count+=1
            total_l_speed+=speed
        animal_count+=1
        total_speed+=speed
    else:
       answer=input("are there any animals?(yes:y/no:n):)")
       if answer != 'y':
           break
```